# Hide bootstrap modal without page reload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I'm using bootstrap 3 modal when I dismiss it the page reloads and `/?`is added to location string. How can I just dismiss and hide modal without page reload?

Comment: You didn't responded to @Kro91 Answer. At least you should reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your button that closes the modal will need to have the data-dismiss attribute and it should be equal to "modal"

```
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

This code is straight from the Bootstrap website (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)